# apache 2 .htaccess Won't redirect www > non-www

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, no-www

I am having a problem with my website where i can't get apache to redirect my site to non-www. eg www.sqlinject.me needs to redirect to sqlinject.me.

Note: I haven't included http(s) because the code I currently have is successfully redirecting http(s):www.sqlinject.me to http(s)://sqlinject.me.

The reason I need it to redirect without the http(s), is because my site is indexed on google, however if you click my site it takes you to www.sqlinject.me which does't redirect.

Here is some info:

I'm hosting with: namecheap
I'm running my site on a raspberry pi running apache2

Here's my .htaccess code for the www redirect:

```
# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Heres the whole .htacces code(just in case):

```
# Set home page to inject.php
DirectoryIndex inject.php

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove .php from file extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Force redirect to https (just incase namecheap fails)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

# Set error pages
ErrorDocument 404 /includes/error-pages/404
ErrorDocument 403 /includes/error-pages/403
ErrorDocument 500 /includes/error-pages/500

# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
```

Comment: `# Redirect www to non-www` rule should be placed just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue